# Testing Login with minitest-rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, minitest

I'm very new to minitest-rails.

Currently, doing test for my login controller.

**First**, do I need to set **encrypted password** in my **users fixtures**?

```
admin:
 fullname: Administrator
 username: admin
 password_digest: $2a$10$RVjBGDtSlmOHCKvgUbqYCuBT1QFQ0NfU6b1WgwLOS3/PFDzwEG4bq
 status: true
 email: test@test.net
 role: admin
 last_updated_by: admin
```

here is my **LoginModule** codes:

```
def authenticate_current_user(username, password)
  User.find_by(username: username).try(:authenticate, password)
end
```

here is my **Login Controller** codes (using **POST** method):

```
def authenticate_login
  user = authenticate_current_user(params[:username], params[:password])
   if user.status == true
     session[:username] = user.username
     session[:user_id] = user.id
     session[:role] = user.role

     flash.keep[:status] = "success"
     redirect_to "/home", :notice => "Hi #{user.username.capitalize}! you have successfully logged in."
   else
     flash.keep[:status] = "error"        
     redirect_to "/login", :notice => "Invalid Username or Password!"
   end
end
```

Here is my **LoginControllerTest** codes:

```
test "should authenticate_login" do
    @user = users(:admin)
    # I tried
    post :authenticate_login, params: { username: @user.username, password: 'pwwadmin' } # Not working

    # and also
    post :authenticate_login, params: { session: {username: @user.username, password: 'pwwadmin'} } # Not working

    assert_not_nil(@user)
    assert_equal session[:username], @user.username
    assert_equal flash[:status], 'success'
    assert_response :success
end
```

**Result:**, always turns to **else** clause. It seems that I'm having trouble with the password?

```
   else
     flash.keep[:status] = "error"        
     redirect_to "/login", :notice => "Invalid Username or Password!"
   end
```

**Please help to fix my login test.**

Answer (score 0):

No password_digest necessary in the fixture. Just use password (and password_confirm if you require the user to enter the password twice). To fake login just set @current_user to your admin fixture.

foo_bar_test.rb:

```
def setup
  @current_user = users(:admin)
end

...
```

Best of luck!

Comment: [The Lowdown on Fixtures](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#the-low-down-on-fixtures) seems to disagree. Bear with me, I'm figuring this out too. ^_^ Like the blind leading the blind up in here.